# Calculating the position of a parallax background (2d)

Tags: math, language-agnostic, background, parallax

I'm trying to align 4 different parallax backgrounds in my game.  These aren't endless tiling backgrounds like in a space shooter, they don't fill the whole screen.  They're a row of trees running along the ground.

My images are bottom left aligned and I'm trying to align them all to the lowest point on the terrain.

I have the following information:  The lowest point on the map that I want everything to line up at (is 300).  The parallax / scroll factor of the background.  The height of the background.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BRlNP.jpg]

I've tried:

```
background.y = lowestPoint; // doesn't work
background.y = lowestPoint * parallaxFactor; // doesn't work, way off
background.y = lowestPoint + lowestPoint * parallaxFactor; // doesn't work
```

I'm obviously missing something here.

Basically, I'm trying to calculate where to put the background tile's registration point based on it's parallax factor and lowest point in the terrain.

Ideas?

Comment: This isn't enough information.  What do you mean by "align"?  What do you mean by "lowest?"  Post a sketch of what you're trying to achieve.  Label it.

Comment: Well, why should paralax be involved in the y coordinate? Shouldnt it concern only horizontal movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly; Screen position is calculated as

```
screenX = (positionX - cameraX) * parallaxFactor
screenY = (positionY - cameraY) * parallaxFactor
```

Then to align two positions with different parallax factors at some camera position, you need to match screen coordinates:

```
obj1.screenY = (obj1.positionY - cameraY) * obj1.parallaxFactor
obj2.screenY = (obj2.positionY - cameraY) * obj2.parallaxFactor

(obj1.positionY - cameraY) * obj1.parallaxFactor =
    (obj2.positionY - cameraY) * obj2.parallaxFactor

obj1.positionY =
    (obj2.positionY - cameraY) * F + cameraY
```

where `F = obj2.parallaxFactor / obj1.parallaxFactor`.

Similarly for the horizontal direction.